# Codeigniter : pagination with query string is not working properly

Tags: codeigniter

I am using query string pagination. I have integrated this successfully. There are some issue with this.

- when i click on second page first time it reloads the page but doesn't append ?per_page to the URL, it does appends like this controller/method/?2
- when i click on second page second time it does the correct behavior but URL becomes like this controller/method/parameter/?0=&per_page=2

but the URL should be if there are not other get parameter

> controller/method/parameter/?per_page=2

how to get this issue fixed ? i have enabled query string like this

```
$config['page_query_string'] = true;
$config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
```

Can anyone suggest what is the wrong in this implementation ? My base url is

```
$config['base_url'] = base_url().'controller/method/parameter/';
```

Basically it is not adding per_page query string if there is no query string already there in URL. How can i fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$config["total_rows"] = 200;
$config["per_page"] = 10;      
$config['num_links'] = 4;
$config['page_query_string']= TRUE;
$config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
$config["base_url"] = base_url().'controller/method/';

//Change uri segment according your url
$config["uri_segment"] = 3;
$this->pagination->initialize($config);
$links = $this->pagination->create_links();
```